# How to Create table in database using XSD file

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xsd

I have XSD schema file i want to create sql server table using xsd file.
In c# console application there is any solution? please provide me.

I have searched several sites but don't get any perfect solution for that please help me.

This is the code I'm using

```
public void BulkLoadData() { 
    SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad loader = new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad(); 
    loader.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SourceDB;Integrated Security=True"; 
    loader.SchemaGen = true; 
    loader.SGDropTables = true; 
    loader.BulkLoad = false; 
    loader.Execute(
        "C:\\pk\\PPMapSchema.xsd", 
        "C:\\pk\\XML_ContractTypesCombined.xml"); 
    } 
}
```

The error I get is

> > Connection string not found

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a table which has a column of type XML and you want to associate the XSD with it? Did you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-schema-collections-sql-server Have you created a table with an XML column yet?

Comment: Thank you nick, but this solution is not working for me

Comment: public void BulkLoadData()
        {           
                SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad loader = new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad();
                loader.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SourceDB;Integrated Security=True";
                loader.SchemaGen = true;
                loader.SGDropTables = true;
                loader.BulkLoad = false;              
                loader.Execute("C:\\pk\\PPMapSchema.xsd", "C:\\pk\\XML_ContractTypesCombined.xml");             
            }       
        }

Comment: above is my code

Comment: Why didn't you post that in the first place? Please post the error.

Comment: Connection string not found

Comment: there is need to create table in sql manually? i am trying dynamically using XSD file

Comment: What line of your code does "Connection string not found" occur on? This sounds like an error in some other part of your code. In this example, the table has to be created first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml-annotated-xsd-schemas-xpath-queries/sqlxml-4-0-net-framework-support-using-bulk-load